# How to show 3 items in an array every time I click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, coffeescript

I am using the code below to show only the first 3 items in an array as default

```
//Hides all but first 3 items in the array
@$('.question_container')[3..-1].hide()
```

Now, I want to display the next 3 items in the array when I click on the button, and the subsequent 3 items when I click on the button again (and repeat).

Currently, I am only able to show ALL remaining items in the array on click with the following code

```
showMoreQuestions: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    @$('.question_container')[3..-1].show()
    false
```

How can I modify the code above so that I will only display 3 items when I click my button?

Comment: What language is that? (Did you forget a tag on your question?)

Comment: @nnnnnn Looks like a combo of C, Pseudo and Javascript using jQuery ^^;

Comment: @nnnnnn I believe it's coffeescript

Comment: sorry, yeap I am using coffeescript. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display 3, then 6, then 9, or 3 then the next 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but if you just selected the ones that were hidden, you should theoretically be able to display the first 3 every time and have it work.

```
showMoreQuestions: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    @$('.question_container:hidden')[0..2].show()
    false
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what behavior you're looking for but maybe something like this will do the trick:

```
showMoreQuestions: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    first = @$('.question_container:visible').length - 1
    @$('.question_container')[first .. first+3].show()
    false
```

You just need to have a look at how many are currently visible and use that to build your slice for `show`. That will reveal three more every time you call `showMoreQuestions`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Ybz8h/

If you want to only show three at a time (rather than reveal three more at at time), then something like this:

```
showMoreQuestions: (e) ->
    @offset ?= 3
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.question_container')[@offset - 3 .. @offset    ].hide()
    $('.question_container')[@offset     .. @offset + 2].show()
    @offset += 3
    false
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/r8Hhb/